Numerical solution to nonlinear integro-differential equation
I am looking to solve the following integro-differential equation numerically
$$\frac{d}{dr}\rho(r)=-\frac{1}{2ABr^2e^{B\rho(r)^2}}\int_{0}^{r}4\pi s^2\rho(s)ds,\space\rho(0)=c,$$
for $0\leq r \leq R$, where $A,B,\space\text{and}\space c$ are positive. The only source I have managed to find which treats this kind of equation is "A new approach for solving a class of nonlinear integro-differential equations" by I.L. El-Kalla (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1007570412002262) which uses the Adomian decomposition method. As in the paper, I was able to use a fixed point argument to show that the equation admits a unique solution if
$$R^2\frac{2\pi}{3}\left(\frac{c}{A\sqrt{2B}e^\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{\pi R^2}{3AB} \right)}+\frac{1}{2AB}\right)\in(0,1).$$
I tried to obtain a series solution $\rho(r)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\rho_{i}(r)$, where the $\rho_{i}$ are determined by the recurrence relationship given in the paper. The recurrence relationship is given as follows:
Let $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2ABe^{Bx^2}}$ and $\tilde{A}_{n}=f(S_{n})-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\tilde{A}_{i}$, where $S_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\rho_{i}(r)$ is the $n-th$ partial sum of the series solution. The $\rho_{n}(r)$ can then be computed from the recursive relation
$$\rho_{0}(r)=c,$$
$$\rho_{n}(r)=\int_{0}^{r}\tilde{A}_{n-1}(s)\int_{0}^{s}4\pi\tau^2\rho_{n-1}(\tau)d\tau ds, \space n\geq1.$$
I was able to show that the series defining $\rho$ is uniformly convergent under the assumptions
$$\frac{4\pi R^2}{3AB}\in(0,1], \space \frac{4\pi R^2||\rho_{0}||_{\infty}}{3e^{\frac{1}{4}}A\sqrt{2B}}\in(0,1).$$
However I am unsure how to show that this series solves the equation.
The other approach I tried was to do a fixed point iteration using the mapping
$$(T\rho)(r)=c-\int_{0}^{r}\frac{1}{2ABs^2e^{B\rho(s)^2}}\int_{0}^{s}4\pi s^2\rho(\tau)d\tau ds.$$
This map is a contraction mapping on a closed ball of suitable radius of $(C[0,R],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ (This is guaranteed if the conditions of the fixed point proof are met). My idea was to discretise the integrals using the trapezoidal rule and approximate the solution on a fixed grid in $[0,R]$. I am however unsure how to show that this discretisation yields an approximation on the grid.
So my questions are:

How can I show the series solution satisfies the integro-differential equation?

How can I show that the approximation given by using quadrature to replace the integrals converges on an equidistant grid?



Formally
$$
\rho''(r)+\left(\frac{1}{2ABr^2e^{B\rho(r)^2}}\int_{0}^{r}4\pi s^2\rho(s)ds\right)'=0
$$
or
$$
\rho''(r)+\left(\frac{1}{2ABr^2e^{B\rho(r)^2}}\right)'\int_{0}^{r}4\pi s^2\rho(s)ds+\frac{1}{2ABr^2e^{B\rho(r)^2}}4\pi r^2\rho(r)=0
$$
then
$$
\frac{2 \pi  e^{-B \rho(r)^2}}{A B}+2 B \rho(r) \rho'(r)^2+\rho''(r)+\frac{2 \rho'(r)}{r}=0
$$

@Cesareo Correct is
$$\rho (r) \left(\frac{2 \pi  e^{-B \rho (r)^2}}{A B}+2 B \rho '(r)^2\right)+\rho ''(r)+\frac{2 \rho '(r)}{r}=0$$

Yes. Thanks! I forgot a $\rho(r)$...

Dear @gpmath, and Cesaro, thank you for your responses. Did you use integration by parts to obtain the final expression? Do you have an approach in mind to solve this equation?

@CarlQuitter See Mathematica notebook MSE_Q5009329

Thank you very much @gpmath.
